# When your image is not resizing in RN

Tags: image, react-native, image-size

I am bringing in an image on my RN app. It's an image of the Simpsons family.  When I set the width and height to 100%, the image becomes too big for my simulator. I want it to be centered and formatted to the center of my screen.  However, when I adjust the percentages, the image starts getting cutoff (obviously). Another thing, the image itself is not centered despite me stating it in the code (see below). Do any of you have any recommendations? This png image is going on top of a background image already (jpeg).

```
<Image
  source={{
   uri:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/Simpsons_
        FamilyPicture.png"               
     }}
   style={{ width: 100 , height: 120, justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center" }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change resizeMode for contain.

Answer (score 0):

justifyContent and alignContent needs to be style attributes of the container. Something like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center"}}>
    <Image
      source={{
       uri:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/Simpsons_
            FamilyPicture.png"               
         }}
       style={{ width: 100 , height: 120}}
     /> 
</View>
```